# Hibernate's validateValue() throws illegal argument exception if a property has no rules?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-validator

I have the following class:

```
class Foo
{
   @NotEmpty
   private String member1;

  @NotEmpty
  private String member2;

  private String member3; //this one is optional, so has no rules
}
```

I have a library to which I add all the property names and corresponding UI fields, each time the UI's `onChange` event occurs, I call `validateValue()` on the given field name for that field, to validate it and show error/success message.

The problem is, in this case where I have no rules for `member3`, if I try to validate it by doing this:

```
String value = event.getValue(); //whatever the new value is now
validator.validateValue(Foo.class, "member3", value);
```

On the 2nd line, I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: member3 is not a valid property of 
com.xxx.Foo
```

Both `member1` and `member2` within the same class, are validated correctly.

Is there anything I can do to avoid getting this exception on the fields that don't have any rules set on them? If not, is there a way (without reflection or specifying it manually for each field) to check if a rule has no rules set on it, so i can avoid calling validateValue on it?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Hibernate Validator are you using? I checked with the latest version (5.1.0.Final) and there it works. If you can I recommend you upgrade.

You can also create an issue in the Validator [issue tracker](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV), reporting your problem and in particular which Validator version you are using.

Last but not least, to answer your question about alternatives. You could use the Bean Validation metadata API to find the constrained properties:

```
validator.getConstraintsForClass(Foo.class).getConstrainedProperties()
```

This will allow you to process only the properties which are acually constrained.

Comment: I'm using 4.1.x, unfortunately I can't upgrade :(